# Quando se faz necessário o padrão model request/response no contexto de uma aplicação REST?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

Se possível, vamos imaginar um contexto onde é utilizado Spring Boot e JPA.

Durante a construção de algumas API REST, sempre fico na dúvida se devo realizar o padrão model request/response. Para exemplificar, consider o seguinte cenário.

Nosso objetivo final é ter uma API que realiza o cadastro de agendamentos, onde um agendamento pode sem abstraído como a seguinte classe em Java:

```java
public class Agendamento {

    private Autor autor;

    private String texto;
}
```

Supondo que cada agendamento tenha necessariamente um autor, utilizando hibernate, nossa classe Entity seria algo parecido com:

```
@Entity
public class AgendamentoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Autor autor;

    private String texto;

}
```

Deste modo, para o cadastro de um agendamento, os campos necessário poderiam ser apenas o `texto` e o `id` do autor. Nos levando para algo do tipo:

```java
public class AgendamentoModelRequest {

    private Long idAutor;

    private String texto;

}
```

Desde modo, o `agendamentoController` receberia um objeto da classe `AgendamentoModelRequest`, que por sua vez seria utilizando por um `AgendamentoService`, fazendo uso de um `AgendamentoRepository` para realizar o cadastro.

Mas, neste caso `Agendamento` é muito parecido com `AgendamentoEntity` (difere pela falta de id), como também será igual ao `AgendamentoModelReponse`. Assim, poderíamos "sobrecarregar" o POJO agendamento para o contexto de model request/response e Entity.

Fazer isso é necessariamente uma má prática? Pois isso facilitaria muito, uma vez que o contexto é sobre `Agendamento`, então o `AgendamentoController` poderia receber o POJO `Agendamento` (anotado com javax.validation/persistence annotations e fasterxml.jackson.annotation) e utilizando-o para o ser o próprio retorno da API.

Answer (score 3):

Razões para se utilizar esta estratégia:

1. Quando você deseja garantir que a interface com a sua API seja imutável
2. Para evitar que sua API apresente comportamento diferente a cada alteração de entidade de banco, correndo o risco de quebrar os sistemas que já estão integrados a ela
3. Para separar a responsabilidade da entidade de banco ser a mesma a ser requisitada/retornada ao cliente, contendo tanto anotações relacionadas à persistência quanto anotações relacionadas à parse (`@Table` e `@JsonIgnore` por exemplo).
4. Para assegurar uma forma mais fácil de realizar testes por camada (*sliced tests*) e garantir que duas camadas diferentes estejam funcionando conforme o esperado

Respondi também [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389876/como-fazer-o-versionamento-no-endere%C3%A7o-de-uri-de-api-rest/390433#390433) um tempo atrás explicando um pouco da estratégia de versionamento de uma API, que vai muito de encontro do porque utilizar estas estruturas.