# Spring Boot - Alterar nomes de propriedades de um objeto ao retornar JSON da API

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, restful

Galera boa noite!
Estou com uma api rest criada com spring boot + hibernate e tudo que tem direito!

Vamos imaginar o seguinte cenário: *O engenheiro de dados criou o banco na seguinte forma*

*TB_PESSOA*

```
no_nome
nu_cpf
sg_uf
dt_aniversario
```

Como vocês fariam para "REMAPEAR" (não sei dar um nome a isso xD) para quando a o recurso da **API** for exposta exibir da forma natural....

```
nome
cpf
uf
aniversario
```

ps: não sei se é possivel "mapear". se alguém tiver uma ideia =)
ps: vou consumir com react, também gostaria de enviar no mesmo padrão (nome,cpf,uf...)

Answer (score 1):

É possível alterar as propriedades no momento da serialização do objeto.

O que acho importante é destacar que essa transformação está mais relacionada com sua classe do que com o modelo de dados, conforme você exemplificou.

Como você não deu detalhes da sua implementação, vou explicar utilizando a classe `Pessoa` como exemplo:

```
import java.util.Date;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Pessoa {    
    private String no_nome;
    private String nu_cpf;
    private String sg_uf;
    private Date dt_aniversario;   
}
```

Algumas considerações:

1. O Spring Boot por padrão pode utilizar Jackson, GSON ou JSON-B para serialização/deserialização de objetos, utilizando seus recursos de auto configuração
2. Cada framework possui suas características e anotações para customizar o payload de resposta, o ideal é verificar a documentação
3. Utilizarei como exemplo o framework **Jackson**

---

Por padrão o Jackson utiliza o nome da propriedade da classe para serialização, dessa forma a classe pessoa resultará neste JSON:

```
{
    "no_nome": "NULLPTR",
    "nu_cpf": "00000000191",
    "sg_uf": "PR",
    "dt_aniversario": "1994-01-01"
}
```

Para alterar este comportamento, utilizamos as anotações do framework de serialização para customizar as propriedades como abaixo:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Pessoa {
    @JsonProperty("nome")
    private String no_nome;
    @JsonProperty("cpf")
    private String nu_cpf;
    @JsonProperty("uf")
    private String sg_uf;
    @JsonProperty("aniversario")
    private Date dt_aniversario;
}
```

Nessa situação o `@JsonProperty` está especificando o nome que o campo deve assumir ao ser serializado, resultando no seguinte:

```
{
    "nome": "NULLPTR",
    "cpf": "00000000191",
    "uf": "PR",
    "aniversario": "1994-01-01"
}
```

É importante notar que as anotações deixam o código cada vez mais carregado e trás mais complexidade, é comum adotar-se DTOs para retornos de APIs e não utilizar-se diretamente da entidade de banco de dados (onde já discuti sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391840/quando-se-faz-necess%C3%A1rio-o-padr%C3%A3o-model-request-response-no-contexto-de-uma-apli/391872#391872)).

Mas, por serem em momentos distintos, é possível utilizar uma entidade JPA conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_PESSOA")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "no_nome")
    @JsonProperty("nome")
    private String algumNome;

    @Column(name = "nu_cpf")
    @JsonProperty("cpf")
    private String algumCpf;

    @Column(name = "sg_uf")
    @JsonProperty("uf")
    private String algumUf;

    @Column(name = "dt_aniversario")
    @JsonProperty("aniversario")
    private Date umaDataDeAniversario;
}
```

Durante a serialização essa classe irá produzir o resultado esperado, porém, note que eu já tive que introduzir um `@JsonIgnore` para não deixar o id do banco de dados aparecer no payload. Isso trás sérios problemas quando seu modelo muda, e o payload de resposta da sua API não deve mudar.

Links:

[Docs Spring Boot - Serialização/Deserialização](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-json-jackson)

[Anotações Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations)

[Entities vs DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572188/microservices-restful-api-dtos-or-not)

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta meu amigo! Foi de grande aprendizado! já tinha pesquisado sobre DTO! agora sei que estou no caminho certo.!

Comment: Ótimo @Kasio não esquece de aceitar a resposta :)