# Utilização apenas de um atributo de uma entidade

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot, entidade-relacionamento

Estou construindo uma API Rest para cadastro de Cidades e Clientes. O meu problema seria em relação à classe Cliente que possui como atributos dados pessoais do cliente e uma Cidade, que seria a cidade de residência relacionada à entidade Cidade.

A entidade **Cidade:**

```
package com.desafio.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cidade")
public class Cidade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "cidade", nullable = false)
    private String nomeCidade;
    @Column(name = "estado", nullable = false)
    private String estado;

}
```

A entidade **Cliente:**

```
package com.desafio.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nome_cliente")
    private String nomeCliente;
    @Column(name = "sexo")
    private String sexo;
    @Column(name = "data_nascimento")
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;
    @Column(name = "idade")
    private Integer idade;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cidade cidade;

}
```

O problema principal é que, no momento em que o Cliente vai fazer o cadastro, logo gerar um POST, no campo onde deveria ter apenas o nome da cidade, solicita todo o objeto Cidade, inclusive o ID.
O Json esperado fica da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "cidade": {
    "estado": "string",
    "id": 0,
    "nomeCidade": "string"
  },
  "dataNascimento": "string",
  "id": 0,
  "idade": 0,
  "nomeCliente": "string",
  "sexo": "string"
}
```

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser feito, para que eu tenha um relacionamento entre as 2 entidades, porém capturando apenas o nome da cidade para a classe Cliente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separar as responsabilidades entre os domínios de sua controladora e base de dados.

Respondi uma pergunta similar a esta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391840/quando-se-faz-necess%C3%A1rio-o-padr%C3%A3o-model-request-response-no-contexto-de-uma-apli/391872#391872) um tempo atrás que engloba o seu dilema, especificamente neste trecho:

> Para separar a responsabilidade da entidade de banco ser a mesma a ser requisitada/retornada ao cliente, contendo tanto anotações relacionadas à persistência quanto anotações relacionadas à parse (@Table e @JsonIgnore por exemplo).

Para o seu caso, você tem a necessidade de customizar o objeto de requisição enviado pelo seu cliente, e está utilizando a sua entidade de banco de dados para isso. Com o decorrer do tempo, a manutenção do seu código vai ficar mais complexa, visto que sua API vai evoluir, e com isso mais dados serão incluídos na requisição, validações deverão ser realizadas...

Uma solução seria adotar a criação de um objeto de `Request` e `Response` para suas operações, com isso você ganharia a flexibilidade de possuir uma classe com apenas os dados que lhe interessam nessa requisição (eliminando campos e estruturas, ou adicionando campos e validações), e não corre o risco de suas propriedades de requisição/resposta mudarem quando houver qualquer alteração em seu banco de dados.